# Problem with numbering equations when using Arabic as the main language

Tags: xetex, equations, numbering, arabic

The following code prevents the number of the equation from appearing.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib, calendar=gregorian]{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.1, WordSpace=2]{Amiri}

\setotherlanguage{english}


\begin{document}


 \begin{equation}
 X=Y
 \end{equation} 



\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem disappears when switching English with Arabic; that is when taking English as the main language.  Also, the problem disappears when one removes [Script=Arabic]; but this makes a disaster if one includes an Arabic text.

Sorry if the question is not well edited.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have Amiri font but tried another font and got no error (but I can not read arabic) do you get a tex error? if so please add the exact error message from the log into your question, use the `{}` button to mark as a code section so lines are preserved

Comment: Can you add  an image showing result after compiling

Comment: @ David Carlisle : It does not seem that on the chosen Arabic font; I tried with three others, and get the same result.

Comment: @Salim Bou: I don't know how to add an image; though when compiling the parenthese "(" appears instead of the number.

Comment: I edited  your question  parenthesis appears like this or without numbers?

Comment: Thank you Salim; there is no number, just one parenthese "(".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used a different font and saw `1)(` as shown in Salim's image. The following forced the `()` to appear in LTR order using this font but possibly won't work for you (I'll delete if not)

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib, calendar=gregorian]{arabic}


\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.1, WordSpace=2]{ScheherazadeRegOT.ttf}

\setotherlanguage{english}

\makeatletter

\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\selectlanguage{english}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}


 \begin{equation}
 X=Y
 \end{equation} 



\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it works;  I'm really thankful.  Can you please add a comment on the main source of the problem; anyway, I don't need such an explanation to be happy!

Comment: @YassineGuerboussa I couldn't trace exactly where it went wrong but `)(` is basically `()` but typeset in the wrong direction so I forced `\setlanguage{english}` into the macro that prints the number (apart from that it is the standard definition) which persuaded it to print left to right.